# iphone-"Use of Undeclared Identifier 'textFieldShouldReturn' Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've hit an "Use of Undeclared Identifier" Error. Seems there could be a lot of reasons for this, and I couldn't see what the problem was with mine. First, here's the code:

```
#import "CMViewController.h"
#import "CMAEncode.h"

@interface CMViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *toCode;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Coded;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *onOrOff;

- (IBAction)StartEncodeDecode:(id)sender;




@end


@implementation CMViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)StartEncodeDecode:(id)sender {

    NSString *finishedText;
    NSString *toCode = self.toCode.text;
    if (self.onOrOff.on == TRUE) {
        finishedText = [CMAEncode encodeText:toCode];
        self.Coded.text = finishedText;
    } else {
    }

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField // Undeclared Identifier here.
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

}
@end
```

I'm trying to make a textfield resign first responder so the keyboard will return. But I really just want to know why this error is occurring, it might help people out with future instances of this error.

Comment: Are you missing a closing } for StartEncodeDecode:?

Comment: Don't write textFieldShouldReturn: method definition inside StartEncodeDecode: method.

Comment: Actually you are trying to use textFieldShouldReturn with UITextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a method inside another method which is not allowed in <strike>any language</strike> objective-c. Please move `textFieldShouldReturn:` after `StartEncodeDecode:` method as below

```
- (IBAction)StartEncodeDecode:(id)sender {
    NSString *finishedText;
    NSString *toCode = self.toCode.text;
    if (self.onOrOff.on == TRUE) {
        finishedText = [CMAEncode encodeText:toCode];
        self.Coded.text = finishedText;
    } else {
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's allowed in Pascal, after a fashion.

Comment: Don't have idea about pascal. I was thinking that someone would comment on `any language` text. Now I know one rule of `Pascal` :)

Comment: It's pretty much a rule that any time you say that feature XXX doesn't exist anywhere, someone will come up with an example where it does exist.  Except for the DWIM instruction.

Comment: And there is one more rule 'If you don't know anything just say it doesn't exists' and suddenly from nowhere someone will let you know that it exists :D

Comment: Wow! stackoverflow is really fast. I think most sites with this many questions, it would take days to get answered. Thanks for the help.